# Parsing CSV with Ansible

Tags: csv, ansible

I need to parse a CSV with Ansible. The issue I'm facing is that I don't have fixed columns, they are variables.
For example: I need to extract network informations and to use them for configure vmware guests networks. In this case I can have a CSV with these:

(other columns) Nic1_Vlan Nic1_IP Nic1_MASK Nic1_Scope (other columns)

Otherwise I can have this:

(other columns) Nic1_Vlan Nic1_IP Nic1_MASK Nic1_Scope Nic2_Vlan Nic2_IP Nic2_MASK Nic2_Scope (other columns )

I can have 1 nic only or 3 in one shot.
Do you have any hint about this scenario? Would you use jinja2 or do you think is better to use a json/yaml variable files?

Thank you for any reply!!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example the play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    rec_len: 4
    delimeter: ' '
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        nics: "{{ (lookup('file', 'data.csv')|trim).split(delimeter) }}"
    - set_fact:
        len: "{{ (nics|length/rec_len)|int }}"
    - set_fact:
        nics_list: "{{ nics_list|default([]) + [[
                       nics[(item*rec_len)|int],
                       nics[(item*rec_len+1)|int],
                       nics[(item*rec_len+2)|int],
                       nics[(item*rec_len+3)|int] ]] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, len|int)|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ nics_list }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'Nic1_Vlan', u'Nic1_IP', u'Nic1_MASK', u'Nic1_Scope']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Nic1_Vlan", 
        "Nic1_IP", 
        "Nic1_MASK", 
        "Nic1_Scope"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'Nic2_Vlan', u'Nic2_IP', u'Nic2_MASK', u'Nic2_Scope']) => {
    "msg": [
        "Nic2_Vlan", 
        "Nic2_IP", 
        "Nic2_MASK", 
        "Nic2_Scope"
    ]
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?